# How to export from sas to excel using a template

Tags: excel, sas, export-to-excel

```
proc export data=data1
    OUTFILE="place_on_pc\template_SASdata.xlsx"
    DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
    sheet=input;  
run;
```

Simple proc export code in SAS. However, I want to use the the "template_SASdata.xlsx" file as an template and save my data on a brand new file with the same sheets as my original excel template but updated 'input' sheet.

```
input="place_on_pc\template_SASdata.xlsx"
output="place_on_pc\data1_SASdata.xlsx"
```

How do I include that in my proc export?
I have tried to add

```
infile = ="place_on_pc\template_SASdata.xlsx"
```

in my proc export but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to copy the original file to the new file first, and then export to replace the sheet you're adding data to.

Alternately, a method I have used and prefer, you can export to a file not related to the template, and then have a VBA macro in the template that you run that you identify the data sheet and the macro opens the data sheet, does whatever with the data, and saves a new file at the end.  I like this if you're going to be doing any other formatting as excel has fairly good tools for what you're doing here.  If you're not doing *any* other formatting, then have SAS copy the file (assuming you are able to use `x` commands in your environment).

```
x 'copy [template file] [new file]'
```